# Advice on how to create repository (Game modding)

Tags: git, github

The problem I am facing is I want to setup version control on a mod i'm making for a game (Fallout4). The problem being I can't seem to find a way to create a repository on an existing folder (fallout's data folder) without it making it's own directory for the repo(Fallout4/data/MyRepoName) which is not what I want. Say these are some of files in my mod:

```
Fallout4/data/myMod.esp
Fallout4/data/scripts/testscript.pex
```

I don't wish to move these files as they have to be where they are to function in game and copying each file I create to a separate folder seems silly.
I'm looking for a solution where I can version control these files without the need to move them to another location. My apologies for my lack of knowledge on git i'm relatively new to it.

Comment: Maybe you will find this link by GitHub useful: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: Wow that simple, well I should have looked harder to find that guide. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Once you've gone through the basics read http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/about-this-site/who-this-site-is-for.html which will help you level up your git knowledge.